# You don't have permission to access add_thumbnail.php on this server when submit form

Tags: php, forms, submit

I am trying to submit the form to server using php which contains only single filed. Here is my html code:-

```
<form action="add_thumbnail.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div id="add_info">
                <center><h3>Add Thumbnainls</h3><div></center>
                <center class="msg"><?php echo $_REQUEST['msg']; ?></center>

                <span class="label_msg">e.g. 28 cm (H) x 56 cm (W) x 28 cm (D) OR 60 cm (H) x 30 cm (diameter)</span>
                <div class="clearboth"></div>
                <div class="title">Dimensions : &nbsp;</div>
                <div class="title_info"><input type="text" name="dimensions_cm" value="<?php echo $fetch['dimensions_cm'];?>" placeholder="cm"/></div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <span class="label_msg">11 in (H) x 22 in (W) x 11 in (D) OR 24 in (H)  x 12 in (diameter)</span>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/></div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Its working fine and submit the values to server but when i put `11 in (H) x 22 in (W) x 11 in (D)` value into textbox i am getting  `You don't have permission to access add_thumbnail.php on this server.`
What i am doing wrong please help me to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: enctype="multipart/form-data" - why this code?

Comment: check your server's error log for details, and/or show the php code processing the form...

Comment: This is probably incorrect apache config.